# Order of waits and notify

Tags: java, wait, notify

Quick question I hope. If I call notify in an object in Java, is it guaranteed not to wake up any thread which waits (strictly) after I called notify. Or in other words, does notify only wake up threads which were already waiting. Presumably, `notifyAll` will behave in the same way.

For example, if the guarantee does not hold, then it would be possible in this order:

1. Thread N obtains the lock, calls notify, and releases the lock.
2. Thread W obtains the lock, calls wait and releases the lock.
3. Thread W is woken by thread N's notify and continues...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

When you call notify one of the threads that are waiting (if any) will be awakened. Threads not currently waiting for this object cannot be awakend and threads not waiting yet (but that will wait later) cannot be awakened either (obviously).

If you call notifyAll then you will wake up all threads currently waiting.

I recommend you read about hit [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html)

Answer (score 0):

Well, javadocs for `notify()` method clearly state that it:

> Wakes up a single thread that **is** waiting on this object's monitor.

Same thing for `notifyAll()`:

> Wakes up all threads that **are** waiting on this object's monitor.

In order to be placed in queue of waiting threads, thread must first obtain lock for the object, then release it and only then some other thread will be able to obtain lock and call `notify()`.

So I guess you don't have to worry about it.